# Subsetting data.table with compound condition

Tags: r, data.table, conditional-statements, subset

This post concerns subsetting data using package data.table based on a compound condition including a logical AND operator, in particular differences in results obtained with & vs &&.

Environment: R version 3.2.1 (2015-06-18), x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit), Windows 10 Pro, data.table 1.9.4.

I’m subsetting data.table used in a regression call; details of the model are suppressed below, but the data clause of the call is reproduced in full.

```
lm( y ~ u + v + w, data=DT[condo != 1 &<&> apt != 1] )
```

Inclusion of the second `&` (in angle brackets) gives an alternate form of the expression.

Data.table DT has approx. 25,000 rows.  Variables `condo` and `apt` are never-null dummies taking values in `{0,1}`.  As it turns out in the instance I’m working on, variable `apt` is always `0`.

Using a single `&` selects rows of DT as desired, excluding rows where `condo == 1`.  When both ampersands `&&` are used, however, no rows are excluded and the regression is run against all of DT.

So my question(s): Why does this happen?  How is package data.table processing the i condition against the rows of DT?  Does the distinguished behavior of `&&` with respect to `condo[1]` and `apt[1]` explain the observed behavior? (In the first row of the data.table, `condo = 0` and `apt = 0`.)

And a bonus question: Under what conditions should a condition such as `condo != 1` be written as `condo != 1L`, given R’s storage of (undeclared) ints as doubles?  This isn’t just an idle question; data subsetting based on the values of dummies arises frequently in my work.

Comment: Sorry -- my question got the wrong title.  it should be: Subsetting R Data.Table with Compound Condition.

Comment: as for the `1` vs `1L` - if your `class(condo)` is `integer`, it'll be more efficient to use `1L`, though the time savings are generally minimal except in heavy loops

Comment: @jackw19 I suppose it's possible that the linked answers might shed light on this question but the behavior of logical tests inside `[.data.table` might not necessarily be as expected. Put in a comment if you want this reopened. It would also be good to post an edit that includes a working example.

Comment: @BondedDust I suppose it's possible that if you read the OP, that might shed light why the linked question answers exactly the issue OP is having ;)

Comment: Scanning the linked answers indicates this is perhaps a somewhat more complex question than I first thought. I'll supply a simple dataset that illustrates my question.

Comment: I'm wondering how data.table evaluates subsetting conditions that don't include the moral equivalent of SQL aggregation functions.  In an SQL select statement, as I understand the data model, the machine / package would grab a row at a time from the from-table, evaluate the where-condition(s) looking at just that current row, output or skip that row, and get on to the next.  I don't know if that describes the way data.table processes i-conditions, or if it uses some deeply clever vectorized method. Presumably that would bear on the workings of scalar vs vectorized logical operators.

Comment: @jackw19 exact same way as pretty most subset operations in R. Any boolean expression is recycled to have same length as the entire `data.table`, so a single `TRUE` selects all of the rows, while e.g. `c(T,F)` would select all odd rows.